# How can I scale down multiple layouts automatically in case there is no space left?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want to create a view that shows 8 items the user can hold. When there are less than 8 items available, the imageView of the item will be replaced by a default image.

The user is able to klick the item and he will see a description of each item in a texbox on the top of the layout. This EditText is placed on top of an image, the "textbox". So far i noticed there is an option to attent an image to the editText, so this problem may be solved.

On the bottom of the layout I want a cancel button on the left side, and an accept button on the right side. This way the user may go back to the game without choosing an item or select an item to use it.

The Problem is, when there is no space left to draw the images at full resolution, the layouts try to draw their content in full resolution. This is why my upper row of items is drawn in full size while the second row is scaled down.

This is how it should look like:

[image]

I then tried the following:

- The root layout is a linear layout
- The first layout is a relative layout, holding the imageview and the
  EditText.
- These are followed by a Linear layout (vertical), parenting
  two other linear layouts (horizontal).
- I put 4 imageViews in each of them, representing the items.

[image]
So far I didn't think about the accept- and cancel buttons, because my result is a total mess yet.
[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textboxview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/textbox" />

        <com.gootsProject.AutoResizeTextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogText"
            style="@style/monologText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView07"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/item_noitem" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView05"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/item_noitem" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/item_noitem" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView06"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/item_noitem" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/item_noitem" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/item_noitem" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/item_noitem" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/item_noitem" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can you help me to setup this view as I intended? I'm lost.

Comment: You should use `TableLayout` or `GridLayout` to hold your items.

Comment: These kind of layouts can be frustrating to get right.  Two tips for you.  Set the background colour of each of the containing layouts so you can easily see which one is doing what.  Second tip is to start with a simple layout and add the complexity back in as you learn how to control each one.  So set the background colours of the relative layout and the two linear layouts within your root view and remove everything else.  Get those right, using the colours trick, then start adding stuff back in.  One step at a time...

Comment: BYW, with a layout like this, I would usually start with a relative layout and control everything through parent alignment and layout_below, layout_toRightOf etc.  Good luck.